# How to user only gmail and press to "To continue" button and save email to database?

Tags: android, android-studio-3.3

I don't want to user signup or sign in process and i want to enter user only gmail/email and press to "To continue" button. if user press button i want to save only gmail address on my database. How i do it on java code?

Here is my simple xml code....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter your gmail here"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Enter your Gmail here"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="To Contunue"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please explain which database are you looking to store locally using sqlite or you have some kind of database on your server ?

Comment: i want to user emails and save them into mysql database.